# Joining numbers in lists sequentially

Tags: r

I have numbers in a list like this:

```
$`1`
 [1]  0.000000  4.583333  6.466667 10.750000 11.166667 12.300000 12.750000 14.350000 15.016667 17.683333 18.533333 19.116667 21.966667 27.750000 31.566667 33.983333 34.700000 38.500000

$`2`
[1]  0.000000  1.383333 15.183333 23.833333 23.833333 23.833333 34.433333 35.766667 40.166667

$`3`
[1]  0.000000  9.633333 11.850000 13.416667 30.700000 53.633333 54.883333 55.116667 56.116667

$`4`
 [1]  0.000000  0.000000  1.783333  2.583333 10.933333 11.216667 14.733333 15.833333 16.033333 16.783333 17.183333 23.733333 23.733333 25.666667 33.700000 34.766667 35.616667 36.833333
[19] 38.516667 40.216667 40.750000 43.500000 45.683333 48.066667 48.283333 48.883333 49.916667 50.516667
```

Data:

```
structure(list(`1` = c(0, 4.58333333333331, 6.46666666666667, 
10.75, 11.1666666666667, 12.3, 12.75, 14.35, 15.0166666666667, 
17.6833333333333, 18.5333333333333, 19.1166666666667, 21.9666666666667, 
27.75, 31.5666666666667, 33.9833333333333, 34.7, 38.5), `2` = c(0, 
1.38333333333334, 15.1833333333333, 23.8333333333333, 23.8333333333333, 
23.8333333333333, 34.4333333333333, 35.7666666666667, 40.1666666666667
), `3` = c(0, 9.63333333333333, 11.85, 13.4166666666667, 30.7, 
53.6333333333333, 54.8833333333333, 55.1166666666667, 56.1166666666667
), `4` = c(0, 0, 1.78333333333333, 2.58333333333333, 10.9333333333333, 
11.2166666666667, 14.7333333333333, 15.8333333333333, 16.0333333333333, 
16.7833333333333, 17.1833333333333, 23.7333333333333, 23.7333333333333, 
25.6666666666667, 33.7, 34.7666666666667, 35.6166666666667, 36.8333333333333, 
38.5166666666667, 40.2166666666667, 40.75, 43.5, 45.6833333333333, 
48.0666666666667, 48.2833333333333, 48.8833333333333, 49.9166666666667, 
50.5166666666667)), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

What I want to do is to make one long vector of the numbers.   They will be joined in the order that they appear in the list. However, there are two extra requirements.

First, the numbers in the second element of the list should be added to the final number in the first element of the list.  Then the numbers in the third element should be added to the final numbers in both of the previous elements ... and so on.

The second requirement is that a 'gap' needs to be added between elements. In this example, I use a gap of 5.

This code works, but I was looking to see if there would be a faster (perhaps data.table) way of speeding it up ?

```
library(dplyr)
gap <- 5
cumes <- lapply(vec, max) %>% unlist 
cumes <- cumes + gap      
cumes <- c(0, cumes %>% cumsum %>% as.numeric)
cumes <- cumes[-length(cumes)]

out<-NULL
for(i in 1:length(cumes)){
  out[[i]] <- vec[[i]] + cumes[i]
}

unlist(out)


[1]   0.000000   4.583333   6.466667  10.750000  11.166667  12.300000  12.750000  14.350000  15.016667  17.683333  18.533333  19.116667  21.966667  27.750000  31.566667  33.983333
[17]  34.700000  38.500000  43.500000  44.883333  58.683333  67.333333  67.333333  67.333333  77.933333  79.266667  83.666667  88.666667  98.300000 100.516667 102.083333 119.366667
[33] 142.300000 143.550000 143.783333 144.783333 149.783333 149.783333 151.566667 152.366667 160.716667 161.000000 164.516667 165.616667 165.816667 166.566667 166.966667 173.516667
[49] 173.516667 175.450000 183.483333 184.550000 185.400000 186.616667 188.300000 190.000000 190.533333 193.283333 195.466667 197.850000 198.066667 198.666667 199.700000 200.300000
```

Comment: You chance to get an answer would be higher if you didn't make unnecessary use of dplyr in your question.

Comment: I happen to like dplyr and as this is a very small part of a long workflow that needs dplyr, I didn't see the need to remove it.

Comment: You are of course free to use dplyr. But I happen to not like the use of pipes in R and are equally free to choose to not answer your question although I might be able to.

Comment: this is likely more a memory issue -  need to do this in bootstrapped simulations from raw data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For speed and memory, you could do this with `inline` and it should give orders of magnitude increase in speed, and also avoid duplicating from calling multiple functions.  For example (might want to change some of the types to `R_len_t` or something),

```
body <- '
    SEXP res;
    int i, j, l, out_len = 0, len = LENGTH(lst), index=0;
    double g, inc = REAL(gap)[0];
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) out_len += LENGTH(VECTOR_ELT(lst, i));
    PROTECT(res = allocVector(REALSXP, out_len));
    double *elem, *rval = REAL(res);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        l = LENGTH(VECTOR_ELT(lst, i));
        elem = REAL(VECTOR_ELT(lst, i)), 
        g = i > 0 ? rval[index-1] + inc : 0.0;  // add the gap and prev max
        for (j = 0; j < l; j++) rval[index++] = elem[j] + g;
    }

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return res;'


library(inline)
cumjoin <- cfunction(signature(lst = 'list', gap = 'numeric'), body=body)

microbenchmark(prev(vec, 5), myfunc(vec, 5), cumjoin(vec, 5))
# Unit: nanoseconds
#             expr    min       lq      mean median     uq    max neval cld
#     prev(vec, 5) 116826 120901.5 128819.38 125127 131165 217350   100   c
#   myfunc(vec, 5)  45584  48301.0  53052.11  51923  53734 108676   100  b 
#  cumjoin(vec, 5)    302    605.0   1117.80   1208   1208  10264   100 a
```

Comment: This would be a bit easier with Rcpp.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (base) function to do it, in about 40% of the previous time:

```
myfunc <- function(data, gaps){
  cumes <- c(0, cumsum(sapply(1:(length(data)-1), function(x) data[[x]][length(data[[x]])] + gaps)))
  unlist(mapply("+", data, cumes))
}
```

And a benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
   prev = {
      cumes <- lapply(vec, max) %>% unlist 
      cumes <- cumes + gap      
      cumes <- c(0, cumes %>% cumsum %>% as.numeric)
      cumes <- cumes[-length(cumes)]
      out<-NULL
      for(i in 1:length(cumes)){
        out[[i]] <- vec[[i]] + cumes[i]
      }
      unlist(out)
  },
  new = myfunc(vec, 5))

Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
 prev 258.818 266.8810 278.1595 275.7135 282.8175 378.626   100   b
  new 100.993 104.8335 113.3042 107.5210 115.2015 324.866   100  a
```

Comment: Perhaps, avoiding the `mapply` in your last line with something like `unlist(data) + cumes[rep(seq_along(data), lengths(data))]` might speed it up a bit?